# How to handle AutoSearch completion using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium Web-driver using JAVA and facing an issue with auto-suggest input text field. When I enter a String "books" in the text field, an option would show up. Then I want to click or select the input populated on the auto suggest menu.

Below is the code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("books");

WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("gwcswTooltip")));

List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements((By.id("gwcswTooltip").name("books on")));

for (WebElement webElement : findElements)
{
  System.out.println(webElement.getText());
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just pick the right locator.

Add the following line

```
List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements((By.xpath("//div[@id='srch_sggst']/div")));
```

instead of

```
List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements((By.id("gwcswTooltip").name("books on")));
```